# Laravel login from external system

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm developing a module with Laravel 5 inside an external system, the external system has its own login and data in another DB, then I had to implement permissions into my Laravel module, so I had to configure a Middleware in the routes, and now i get 2 login screens, I just need to log into Laravel using the external system, i created the same credentials in laravel's user table, so i want to check external username against laravel username, get the password and auto-login into laravel.
   where to do this is the main problem i face.

[image]

I need this screen to autologin
[image]

Routes middleware:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:admin,access_backend']], function(){

Route::get('dashboard', 'dashboardController@dashboard');
.....
.....
```

I Get username from external system using guzzle

```
$client = new Client(); //GuzzleHttp\Client
$result = $client->get($url);
$body = (string)$result->getBody();
```

this is what i'm trying in role middleware:(guess it fails with the password hash , i always get the login screen)

```
 $resp = User::select('username','password')->where('username',trim($body))->first();
    $password = (bcrypt($resp->password));

    if (Auth::attempt(['username' =>$resp->username, 'password' => $password])){
    dd('Hello world');
    return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
       /* ->route('admin/dashboard')
        ->with('Welcome! Your account has been successfully created!'); */
    }  

  if (Auth::guest()) {

      return redirect(url(config('backpack.base.route_prefix').'/login'));
    }
```

Comment: does first login page redirect's to your page after login ? By "get the password", do you mean to get it from your DB ?

Comment: @jaysingkar once i login with external system , it  loads view with external menu, on the left, then i click on any menu link and I get laravel's login  screen

Comment: Why are you hashing the password yourself before passing to `Auth`? You should provide a plain text password to `Auth`, and it will internally hash the password itself.

Comment: @fubar i didn't know that